# Python stops iterate over array after sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this code return nothing?

```
a = [1,2,3]

a = reversed(sorted(a))
s = sum(a)

for k in a:
    print(k)
```

This code, though, works fine:

```
a = [1,2,3]

a = reversed(sorted(a))
# s = sum(a)

for k in a:
    print(k)
```

Comment: Because in Python 3, `reversed` returns an iterator, which `sum` consumes. If you want to use it more than once, you could cast it to a list first.

Comment: Thank you. Can you make it as an answer, so I can mark it?

Comment: @Cairnarvon In Python 2 as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reversed()` [returns an iterator](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#reversed). This is a special object the function creates which can be iterated over once, giving the results in reverse order. This means that the second time you try to iterate over it, it no longer has any contents.

If you want to iterate over the results multiple times, you have to convert it to an actual collection by passing it to `list` or `tuple`.

Comment: @Nicklas but `tee` still needs to internally store the data, so it won't buy you anything in this use case. The main advantage of `tee` is when you iterate over both iterators simultaneously, in which case you don't need to store a history.

Comment: @Antimony: You are absolutely right. Also, sorting is not possible fast in constant memory anyway, so even if it would evaluate the generator twice (which it can't), it wouldn't save you anything

Comment: You could also just do `sorted(a, reverse=True)`

Comment: @Niklas, you can sort in constant memory with bubble, selection, or inerstion sort. You just can't do it with the `O(nlogn)` algorithms.

Comment: @Antimony: Yeah, but quadratic sorting usually isn't an option

Comment: @Antimony Even the ones you mentioned do not take constant memory (memory needed to store indices depends on the size of data), thus the proper term is "in-place" and it's quite easy to do in  ``O(n logn)`` using heapsort.

Comment: @lqc When discussing practical algorithms, people generally just treat pointers as constant size. Theoretically, there are extra `logn` factors when arbitrary integer math is invoked, but noone really cares about that.

Comment: @jamylak No. Initial heapification can be done in-place with linear time: http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify.